# How to filter for NaN when it is a float type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to filter column 1 so that it only returns NaN values. For some reason, NaN is a float type while everything else such as apple and duck are strings.

I've tried these lines below and it doesn't work because NaN is not null but is a float.

```
filtered_df = df[df['1'].isna()]
```

and

```
filtered_df = df[df['1'].isnull()]
```

| 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- |
| NaN | **apple** |
| **duck** | **duck** |
| NaN | NaN |

desired outcome:

| 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- |
| NaN | **apple** |
| NaN | NaN |

Extra question: Can I change the NaN to a None value instead of a float?

Comment: If `NaN` is a float type, then `isnull` should work. You might have a str type here.

Comment: You might have the actual word "NaN" not `np.nan` or `pd.NA`. Which would explain why `isna` and `isnull` are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

df[df.A1.isnull()]

For Pandas DataFrame, this code works, but change the column names to start with an alphabet. Also remove the square bracket around the column name, A1